# Injecting dependency with Guice works on one method and not on the other

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

My app is experiencing a "weird" Guice problem. Somehow a service is injected in one method and not on the other. I am not sure why:

```
public class MyServerResource {

    @Inject
    MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        if(myService == null){
            // This one is not thrown
            throw new RuntimeException("Service is null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void get() {
        if(myService == null){
            // This one is  thrown
            throw new RuntimeException("Service is null");
        }
    }

}
```

In the create() method, the service is not null, while in the get() method the service is null. What kind of Guice behavior is this? Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: How are you injecting the class and then calling these methods?

Comment: Yes, in the actual call, there is a call to the myService.functions(), however just before that, there is the myService == null check first

Comment: I saw the problem now, it was with the base class (with makes the class Guice-enabled) of MyServerResource which is not being called

Comment: Note you can have this problem if the constructor calls the methods. This is yet another reason why constructor injection is better.

Comment: Note that your code sample is not complete, some of your methods are annotated  `@Override` but there isn't a super class.

Answer (score 4):

Prefer constructor injection over field and method injection.

```
public class MyServerResource {

  private final MyService myService;

  @Inject
  public MyServerResource(MyService myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
  }

  @Override
  public void create() {
    // myService isn't null here
  }

  @Override
  public void get() {
    // myService isn't null here
  }
}
```

This approach has a lot of benefits:

- "Immutable" classes (class members are initialized in constructor)
- Better unit test cases. You just need to provide a mocked service to constructor.